# what is/are the difference(s) between a full spectrum camera, a UV-VIS-NIR camera, and a monochrome camera

Tags: monochrome

I was asked to shoot UV, RGB, and NIR images using a camera. Images collected from this camera will be used for the target detection. For UV, the central wavelength is 350nm, for NIR, the central wavelength is 950nm. My idea is to use a converted a full spectrum camera plus different filters for each image type, but someone told me a monochrome camera could be better option because it is more sensitive.

May I know the difference between those cameras, and which one is better for my application?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi and welcome to Photo.SE! Please [edit] your question to include [any research[(https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you've done so far. Even if it's minimal, or you found things which didn't make sense, please include it. A good way to start your research (if not already done), is to search the web or look at the relevant tags on this site (e.g. [tag:uv] or [tag:infrared]).

Comment: By "full spectrum" do you mean a sensor with a 3-color Bayer filter? Fujifilm XTrans filter? Foveon unfiltered?  Front- or back-side illuminated? etc. See Edmund's camera type guide: https://www.edmundoptics.com/knowledge-center/application-notes/imaging/understanding-camera-sensors-for-machine-vision-applications/